# How to reduce size of modified PDF using pymupdf

Tags: python, pymupdf

I'm editing a pdf by redacting certain words and adding different words on top of the redacted area in pymupdf.

The code works successfully however it makes a very large single page pdf (9MB). I assume this is because of drawing many shapes and redactions but I can't seem to refactor.

I know [from this post](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/465) that I shouldn't be applying `page.apply_redactions()` more than once but if I don't the text doesn't correctly display on top of the redacted square, or it raises `ValueError: fill rect must be finite and not empty`.

Any help in refactoring for a smaller output pdf would be much appreciated.

```python
    doc = fitz.open(self.path) 
    # get pdf background colour
    col = fitz.utils.getColor("py_color")
    # iterating through pages 
    for page in doc: 

        page.wrap_contents()
        # geting the rect boxes which consists the matching regex 
        sensitive = self.get_sensitive_data(page.getText("text") 
                                            .split('\n')) 
        for data in sensitive: 
            areas = page.searchFor(data) 
            for area in areas:
                text_page = page.get_textpage(clip=area)
                text_page = text_page.extractDICT(area)
                # text_page = area
                max_length = fitz.getTextlength(str(max(column, key=len)), fontsize=fontsize)+14
                area = format_border(page, area, data, fontsize, align=align, max_length=max_length)
                area.y1 = add_yrect_line(column, area.y1, area.y1-area.y0)
                col = fitz.utils.getColor("white")
                redaction = page.addRedactAnnot(new_area, fill=col, text=" ") #flags not available
                page.apply_redactions()  # page.apply_redations(images=fitz.PDF_REDACT_IMAGE_NONE) to circumvent transparent image issues
                writer = fitz.TextWriter(page.rect, color=color)
                # align to top of box if align right:
                writer.fill_textbox(new_area, variable, fontsize=fontsize, warn=True, align=align, font=font)
                writer.write_text(page)
                # To show what happened, draw the rectangles, etc.
                shape = page.newShape()
                shape.drawRect(new_area)  # the rect within which we had to stay
                shape.finish(stroke_opacity=0)  # show in red color
                shape.commit()

                shape = page.newShape()
                shape.drawRect(writer.text_rect)  # the generated TextWriter rectangle
                shape.drawCircle(writer.last_point, 2)  # coordinates of end of text
                shape.finish(stroke_opacity=0)  # show with blue color
                shape.commit()
                writer = fitz.TextWriter(area, color=color)
```

Answer (score 6):

A little bit hard to tell without knowing more detail about the PDF page you are dealing with.
Inserting text or drawings does not add high data volumes however. So I presume that applying redactions may cause the issue:
If your page contains images that overlap any of your redaction rectangles, the `apply_redactions()` (with no arguments!) will modify the overlapping image parts and blank them out ... this will happen for every image and each of its overlaps! The result is an **uncompressed** new PNG version of each image.
So you should try one of the following:

- do not touch any images: use `page.apply_redactions(images=fitz.PDF_REDACT_IMAGE_NONE)`
- remove every image with at least one overlap (may be undesireable): `page.apply_redactions(images=fitz.PDF_REDACT_IMAGE_REMOVE)`
- or, at least, use `garbage=3, deflate=True` when saving the file to compress modified images.

Actually you should always use garbage collection and compression after these types of operation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, not touching images helped - I should have been more specific about my question: is this process of applying a redaction then rendering text over the top the most efficient way of 'writing over text', or is there a better way? I tried several other combinations but most rendered rectangles on top of the new text too (including applying redactions at the end).

Comment: @polymath - let me also invite you to the "Discussions" of my repository.  You can specify replacing text directly with the annotation. I haven't seen your reason, why you use `text = " "`.